# Web Service / Forms: Architecture and Framework Question

Tags: java, web-services, architecture

We have the following architecture in mind: 
To an existing application, we would like to add a web service front end. 
The web service will be used from a web portal, which runs on a different web server. 
So, we will not use a database on this different web server and just forward entries from the web portal to the web service and show what the web service returns. 
First question: what do you think about this architecture?
Second question: Can you recommend a java framework for this web server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the second question: one possibility is to use [WSRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_for_Remote_Portlets) with [Java Portlets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Portlet_Specification).